# Serialization on self referenced entity

Tags: php, symfony, api-platform.com

I wonder if it's possible to have different properties shown on GET operation to an embedded entity.

Here is my class :

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="folders")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\FolderRepository")
 */
class Folder
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Folder", inversedBy="childFolders", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="folder_parent", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $parentFolder;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Folder", mappedBy="parentFolder", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $childFolders;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="File", mappedBy="folder", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_folder", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $files;
}
```

The result I want to get :

```
{
    "@context": "\/contexts\/Folder",
    "@id": "\/api\/folders\/561",
    "@type": "Folder",
    "id": 561,
    "name": "SOURCE(6)",
    "parentFolder": {
        "@id": "\/api\/folders\/52",
        "@type": "Folder",
        "id": 52,
        "name": "ashirama workspace",
        "parentFolder": null
     },
     "files": [
        {
            "name": "file(1).png"
        }
      ]
}
```

The actual result :

```
{
    "@context": "\/contexts\/Folder",
    "@id": "\/api\/folders\/561",
    "@type": "Folder",
    "id": 561,
    "name": "SOURCE(6)",
    "parentFolder": {
        "@id": "\/api\/folders\/52",
        "@type": "Folder",
        "id": 52,
        "name": "ashirama workspace",
        "parentFolder": null,
        "files": [
              {
                   "name": "file(1).png"
              }
         ]
      },
     "files": [
        {
            "name": "file(2).png"
        }
     ]
}
```

I would like to have files only on actual folder.
I think there is something I don't understand, but maybe there's a known recipe for that use case.

Thank you.

Comment: You could try the jms serializer package where you are able to adjust the depth. Another approach would be the data-transfer-object pattern.

Comment: @corax228 Ok, I'll take a look, thanks.

Comment: @bradconor were you able to solve this issue in api platform ?

Comment: return [DTO's](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/dto/) instead of Entities, set the $parentFolder of each to the parent Folder (Entity, not a DTO). Use a [serialization group](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/serialization/#using-serialization-groups) to get the right output for each class.